# Can I host JSON file in Spring Cloud Config Server?

Tags: java, json, spring, config, spring-cloud

We are using Spring Cloud Config Server to host all configurations for our Spring Boot applications. We want a huge JSON text to be retrieved from the Config Server.

Our current approach is to define the json text as a property value

```
myproperty.jsontext="{'name':'value'}"
```

***Apart from defining the JSON text as a property value, is there any way to host & fetch it from the config server ?***

Does Spring Cloud Config Server support a .json file ?

Update (additional Question):

Can i access the searchLocations property as follows ?

```
@Value("${spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations}
```

while acessing, we keep getting the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations' in string value "${spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations}"
```

Comment: Not currently.  What do you want to do with the json file?  We have an open issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/147

Comment: i want a JSON text in my Spring Boot application and this JSON text to come from an external file. I can use a property holding the JSON text as its value but, since the text might grow huge in size, it might not be easy to maintain if it is stored like a proper=value format. Is there any other better way to do this ?

Comment: Not with config server.

Comment: @spencergibb  how about fetching the 'searchLocations' property of Config Server in my Spring Boot application ? Is that possible ?

Comment: config server doesn't return its own configuration, but you could put something like `searchLocations` in `application.yml` that applies to all applications.

Answer (score 4):

there's the possibility to serve arbitary files. It boils down to using the endpoint `/{name}/{profile}/{label}/{path}` with `{path}` being the actual filename... So e.g. `/a-bootiful-client/default/master/myjson.json` will give you the file contents. However by default the content-type of the response will not be `application/json` but `text/html;charset=UTF-8`.

However it will also work with "Accept: application/json":

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8888/a-bootiful-client/default/master/a-bootiful-client.json
{
        "propName":"propValue"
}
```

See the documentation here: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/1.4.3.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_serving_plain_text

Answer (score 3):

## Workaround

Since `yaml` is a subset of `Json`, you can store a `Json` content inside of a `Yaml` file.

- Create q file config.yaml
- Add the Json content in it
- Request the file in `yaml`, `json` and `properties` and everything works!

I have tested this approach when integrating an existing Node.js app to Config Service where all the configs were in `.json` file. So, I just renamed all of them and added to a Config Repo.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate on this? I am not sure I understand your solution. In our use case we have a SPA that neeeds to have endpoints configured and we are using SCC for everything so might as well use it to serve up the JSON file.

Comment: @Astronaut The problem is storing `json` files, which is not supported... However, SCC already supports retrieving the same properties in `yml`, `json` and `property` files by API calls as shown in the answer below. My solution is a workaround to storing a json file, say `myservice.json` in a file called `myservice.yml` whose content is a json object. SCC will use the yml file and load it using the same parser, which an properly parse the json content based on what I explained.

Comment: Thank you for your additional comments. I will probably use the version below so that I don't have to write an Angular client to get the properties.

Answer (score 2):

I have submitted the feature support to Spring Boot at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4027#issuecomment-144649875. Let me know if that works for you...

Answer (score 1):

```
public class JsonPropertySourceLoader implements PropertySourceLoader {


    private static final String JSON = "json";

    @Override
    public final String[] getFileExtensions() {
        return new String[] { JSON };
    }

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> load(final String name,
        final Resource resource, final String profile) {

         final Map<String, Object> source = process(resource);
         return new MapPropertySource(name, source);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Map<String, Object> process(final Resource resource) {
        Map<String, Object> map = null;
        try {
            map = new ObjectMapper()
                .readValue(resource.getFile(), LinkedHashMap.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return map;
    }

}
```

Comment: Add the specific class to read json file on spring cloud config server

Comment: I had sent a patch at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4027#issuecomment-144649875 Verify it and let me know if that works for you...

Comment: Now PropertySourceLoader contract is changed. no more can be used this as a soln.