# Getting File Content from Spring Config Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

I have my application's properties (.properties) like below

```
spring.datasource.url=xxxxx
spring.datasource.username=xxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

database.querymapper=policybyownerqueryconfig.json
```

I would like to configure my application to connect to Spring config server and get the content of **policybyownerqueryconfig.json**. policybyownerqueryconfig.json is a file with some JSON values. How to get the content of this file from spring config server?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698783/can-i-host-json-file-in-spring-cloud-config-server Check this out

Comment: I have a file with JSON data. I want the content of the file from config server as Resource or FileInputStream or something else so that I can parse it in client end. How to achieve that. As mentioned in the question database.querymapper value is a file name, I want its content from config server.

Comment: I can get the file content in browser using URL http://localhost:10081/config/<profile name>/<service name>/policybyownerqueryconfig.json.  How to bootstrap this with EurekaClient